# Is there a shorthand for prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Recently I've started to use prepared statements. However, I feel like my code becomes a bit too cluttered with all the temporary variables and extra lines required just to make a single query.

So far my code looks like the following:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['location_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($location_id, $owner);
//all the other $stmt->fetch() related code here...
```

Are there any shorthand methods to do the same thing?

Comment: if you're using `bind_result`, I don't think you need `store_result`. Other than that though, what exactly is too lengthy about four lines of code?

Comment: @Phil With four lines it's not bad, but when I want to make multiple SQL queries it starts to get a bit cluttered and the code is less readable.

Comment: there is a plethora "wrappers" you could use [*](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqli+wrapper).. ie. `$result = $db->find('locations', 'location_id = ?', [$_GET['location_id']])` - had 10 downloads on [mine](https://github.com/phppackage/pdo-wrapper) or [mine](https://github.com/lcherone/autorm) woop ;p

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @LawrenceCherone.

Comment: To directly answer your question @PotatoGun, "no". Executing prepared statements requires three unique operations... 1) Prepare, 2) Bind, 3) Execute. After that there are several methods for retrieving results so that's a little out of scope. If that's too lengthy or repetitive for you, you're more than welcome to encapsulate that into a reusable method or use a 3rd party implementation.

Comment: First thing I did when I took a job doing PHP was to write my own CRUD object, because I couldn’t stand the mind numbing `$conn` and `$stmt` and `$q1` and `$rs1` ad nauseum.  I would also recommend PDO over mysqli. Take a look at this [PDO wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper)

Comment: This is a great question unjustly closed and downvoted. Duplicated of course but it doesn't make it less great. Only a handful of  PHP users ever manage to ask it at all, preferring to write shining ranks of repetitive operators. @Phil, although there isn't a shorthand out of the box, a *programmer* could  *create* one. And, given mysqli being such illogical mess, offer a hand in creating it.

Comment: @PotatoGun [here you go](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple)

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's open now.

Comment: Cheers @YourCommonSense, great resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using prepared statements is the correct way to execute SQL statements in PHP, and I have to sincerely commend you for doing it the right way.

However, as you have noticed the API is not suitable to be used barebone in an application code. Most modern PHP applications use PDO and even then it's used with some kind of abstraction layer. These APIs were not designed to be used on their own.

If you must use mysqli then you can write a very simple wrapper class yourself. The wrapper should at least have two things. An easy and intuitive way of opening the connection with default parameters and a simple one-liner method for executing prepared statements.

Consider my example:

```
<?php

class DBClass extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($host, $user = null, $pass = null, $db = null, $port = null, $socket = null) {
        // enable error reporting
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        // instantiate mysqli
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port, $socket);
        // set the correct charset
        $this->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    }

    /**
     * Executes prepared statement
     *
     * @param string $sql SQL query with placeholders e.g. SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id=?
     * @param array $params An array of parameters to be bound
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function safeQuery(string $sql, array $params = []): ?array {
        // prepare/bind/execute
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        if ($params) {
            $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($params)), ...$params);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        // If the query produces results then fetch them into multidimensional array
        if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
            return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        }
        // return nothing if the query was successfully executed and it didn't produce results
        return null;
    }

    public function row(string $sql, array $params = []): ?array {
        return $this->safeQuery($sql, $params)[0] ?? [];
    }

    public function single(string $sql, array $params = []) {
        $data = $this->row($sql, $params);
        return array_shift($data);
    }
}
```

This is a simple class that extends mysqli and adds 3 new methods to it: `safeQuery`, `row` and `single`. You can use them to execute a static query or a prepared statement and retrieve multiple rows, a single row, or a single value respectively.

Here is how one would use such class instead of mysqli:

```
$db = new DBClass('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');

// select multiple rows
$id = 2;
foreach ($db->safeQuery('SELECT title FROM movie WHERE directorId=?', [$id]) as $row) {
    echo $row['title']."\n";
}

// select a single row
$movie = $db->row('SELECT id FROM movie WHERE title=?', ['Titanic']);
if ($movie) {
    echo $movie['id']."\n";
}

// select a single column from a single row
echo $db->single('SELECT title FROM movie WHERE id=1');
```

Worth pointing out is that the `store_result()` and `bind_result()` methods are not extremely useful and using them can lead to a dirty code. If you use an abstraction class even as simple as the one demonstrated here you can save yourself the trouble of binding the variables and fetching them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2022, PHP8.2 allows you to enjoy much more concise prepared statement execution.

For your sample snippet, querying for a specific location id and returning a flat, associative array can be written as a single line.

Code: ([PHPize.online Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/b3c1775d2a731a86825bd1cbc4195ba2/php/php82/753b80b3d0fbb3c0433a14bf91b73707/))

```
var_export(
     $mysqli->execute_query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_id = ?", [2])->fetch_assoc()
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'location_id' => 2,
  'owner' => 'Potato Gun',
)
```

Some reference material:

- https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mysqli_execute_query
- https://medium.com/@parvej.code/feature-that-are-accepted-for-php-8-2-f01722b5a658
- https://kinsta.com/blog/php-8-2/#new-mysqli_execute_query-function-and-mysqliexecute_query-method