# $stmt returned from function is different than inside the function

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is the function where I create a DB connection:

```
function get_db_connection()
{
    $host = "127.0.0.1:3306";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "crm";

    return mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
}
```

Here is a function where I use my query:

```
function query_user_by_username($username)
{
    $conn = get_db_connection();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    //var_dump($stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc());

    return $stmt;
}
```

When I execute `var_dump` inside the function I get `NULL` which is perfectly fine response for current scenario.

However, when I call this function from another place, I get an error when executing that same `var_dump`.

Example code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../db/dbh.inc.php');

$db_response = query_user_by_username("zxc");
var_dump($db_response->get_result()->fetch_assoc());
```

When this is executed, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/src/signinscreen/repo/signin.inc.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/src/signinscreen/repo/signin.inc.php on line 17

For some reason, `$stmt->get_result()` inside the function is an actual `object` but when returned from the function, it is `bool`.

Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: You need to help yourself first. Look at the error message. it says fetch_assoc() is called. Now look at the code. fetch_assoc() is nowhere can be seen. Make the code and the error message match first.

Comment: @Dharman I did as per that tutorial, however I am not getting any other message than the I already posted. Furthermore, I am getting correct response when I am inside the function, so this is clearly not problem with `query` or anything mysql related

Comment: However, there is one more option. Your `get_db_connection()` might be creating a new instance of mysqli connection everytime. Please also show us the contents of that function.

Comment: @Dharman I have updated my post with another function that I use and an actual re-producable example, please check

Comment: @YourCommonSense  I have updated my post with another function that I use and an actual re-producable example, please check

Comment: Yes, see. Your `get_db_connection()` is returning a fresh instance each time so when you leave the function GC is collecting it and discarding your result.

Comment: @Dharman should we repopen so you could write an answer?

Comment: What would be the best solution for this to avoid such behavior? Create a class which would contain all the necessary functions with `static` get_db_connection function?

Comment: The best solution would be to use PDO instead of mysqli. If you want to continue using mysqli then you should only create one instance of mysqli and pass it as an argument to your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `get_db_connection()` it creates a new instance of the mysqli class and opens a connection to the MySQL server. This object lives as long as you have a PHP variable pointing to it. In your case the connection is alive only within the scope of your `query_user_by_username()` function.

Prepared statements in mysqli are by default producing unbuffered results. The results are not fetched from MySQL server automatically and you need to call `get_result()`, `store_result()` or fetch them row by row. To fetch the result set from the server the connection must be open.

When you leave the `query_user_by_username()` function, PHP will close the connection and discard any remaining results. When you try to fetch the result set using `get_result()` outside the function, there are no results to be fetched because the connection is closed.

To fix this problem you should pass the mysqli connection as an argument to the function.

```
function query_user_by_username(mysqli $conn, $username)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
```

Then you should ensure that the connection lives for as long as your code needs it. Effectively it means you should create only one instance of mysqli class and pass it as an argument to functions that require it.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../db/dbh.inc.php');
$conn = get_db_connection();

$db_response = query_user_by_username($conn, "zxc");
var_dump($db_response->get_result()->fetch_assoc());
```

As you can see, mysqli is a low-level API that makes handling database operations difficult. For this reason it is better to use PDO. If you wish to continue using mysqli then you can consider writing a [wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64884939/1839439) or write your function in such a way that they never expose the underlying mysqli functions to your business layer. For example:

```
function query_user_by_username(mysqli $conn, $username): ?array
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    // only return the data, not the mysqli object
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()
}
```